# Error when i try to retrieve an MTOM response by a CXF client

Tags: java, cxf, mtom

I'm sending a non-MTOM request and need to retrieve an MTOM response. Problem is:

If I set my bindingProvider with "mtomEnabled = true", the server won't handle the request. If I don't, the client won't handle the response...

```java
try {
    final ArchivePcirWS archivePcirWS = 
          new ArchivePcir(new URL("file:../../link/EchangesExternes/FluxInterSI/EchangesSphereSociale/services/v1/ArchivePcir_1.wsdl"),
                          new QName("http://link/EchangesExternes/FluxInterSI/EchangesSphereSociale/Services/v1", "ArchivePcir"))
                         .getArchivePcirPort();

    final BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider) archivePcirWS;
    bp.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, "http://localhost:8080/zf1interopsr-ws/soapimsa2interopsr/v1/ArchivePcir/v1/MSA/CDC");

    final SOAPBinding sb = (SOAPBinding) bp.getBinding();
    bp.getRequestContext().put(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS, Collections.singletonMap("Content-Type","application/xml"));

    //sb.setMTOMEnabled(true);
    archivePcirWS.recupererArchivePcir(request);

} catch (final Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```